# How to rollapply over a multi column data table

Tags: r, data.table, rollapply

I would like to use the rollapply function over a multi column datatable, namely I would like to be able to use each column independantly for instance let's consider the following datable :

```
> DT = data.table(x=rep(c("a","b","c"),each=3), y=c(1,3,6), v=1:9)
> DT
   x y v
1: a 1 1
2: a 3 2
3: a 6 3
4: b 1 4
5: b 3 5
6: b 6 6
7: c 1 7
8: c 3 8
9: c 6 9
```

Then I would like to use rollapply as a rolling subset in order to work out the rolling mean over 3 element of columns 2 and 3 and store them into external variables :

```
> r1= NA; r2 = NA
> ft=function(x) { r1=mean(x[,2,with=FALSE]) ; r2=mean(x[,3,with=FALSE]) }
> rollapply(DT, width=3, ft)
 Error in x[, 2, with = FALSE] : incorrect number of dimensions
```

Except I got this error which isn't handy, why isn't it working ?

The output would be :

```
> r1
[1] 3.333333 3.333333 3.333333 3.333333 3.333333 3.333333 3.333333
> r2
[1] 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there and can do:

```
lapply(DT[,2:3], function(x) rollapply(x,width=3, FUN=mean))
#$y
#[1] 3.333333 3.333333 3.333333 3.333333 3.333333 3.333333 3.333333

#$v
#[1] 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

Answer (score 3):

Just to add another option using `data.table` only

```
library(data.table) # v1.9.6+
```

Define the rolling mean function

```
rollMean <- function(x, n) Reduce(`+`, shift(x, 0L:(n - 1L)))/n
```

Apply it on multiple columns while specifying `.SDcols`

```
DT[, lapply(.SD, rollMean, 3L), .SDcols = y:v]
#           y  v
# 1:       NA NA
# 2:       NA NA
# 3: 3.333333  2
# 4: 3.333333  3
# 5: 3.333333  4
# 6: 3.333333  5
# 7: 3.333333  6
# 8: 3.333333  7
# 9: 3.333333  8
```

Comment: I guess you can use `roll_mean` from `library(RcppRoll)`

Comment: @akrun I thought of that, but wanted to show a `data.table` answer only :). I guess you can add that separately or edit Colonels answer

Comment: you can edit one of the answer or propose yours I do not really mind. But good proposal ;) And +1 for reduce & shift even if it is a little but overkill!

Comment: @ColonelBeauvel I don't think it's an overkill and my guess it's by far faster than `zoo::rollapply` for big data sets. But `RcppRoll::roll_mean` will probably be the fastest.

Comment: @ColonelBeauvel  You can add that in your post.  I am not posting.

Comment: @DavidArenburg, I am really new to data.table, could you explain what does .SD, 3L and .SDcols does?

Comment: @blackknight316 Please read [this](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-intro.html). Everything is explained there.

Comment: @DavidArenburg, your suggestion worked! thanks a lot!